# Where can I send my motherboard to get it fixed?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, repair

After doing the tests suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1575997/597763) it seems that my Gigabyte AORUS X399 Gaming 7 is completely dead.

However it has not be stressed at all from my user perspective: barely used it one year, but probably less.

Maybe some power surges have broken it, but I guess the manufactor could fix it, so my question is: are there any viable option to get a motherboard fixed?

- I see Gigabyte is in Taiwan, and I'm in Italy, so I guess sending the mobo there and back here could be a big expense; plus they could be ultimately unable to fix it (I guess I should not pay to get it back in that case).
- Are there any certified-places in the world (hopefully in Europe) where I can send the mobo for fixing it?

I paid that motherboard 360€ and it died after having done practically ***nothing*** with respect to its level.

Comment: If its less than a year old, your motherboard may/should still be under warranty. Contact the store you bought it from or use the RMA process provided by the motherboard manufacturer (http://it.gigabyte.com/support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manufacturer will not repair a motherboard because repairing it will be more expensive than to simply replace it. A hobby technician may try to recap it, but that's as far as it goes and it is not a guarantee it will work.

If the motherboard is within warranty, you can get it replaced, otherwise, you'll have to buy a new one. If a powersurge is the cause for the failure, your parents may have insurance.